# Page does not open when clicked on URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
private string sendEmail(string emailId,string userID)
        {
            try
            {               
                userID = Encrypt(userID);
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(emailId);
                mail.From = new MailAddress("");
                //mail.Subject = "Your password for account " + emailId;
                string userMessage = "http://localhost/LoginWithSession/ResetPassword" + userID;

                userMessage = userMessage + "<br/><b>User Id:</b> " + emailId;
                //userMessage = userMessage + "<br/><b>Passsword: </b>" + password;

                string Body = "<br/><br/>Please  click on link to reset your password:<br/></br> " + userMessage + "<br/><br/>Thanks";
                mail.Body = Body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //SMTP Server Address of gmail
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("harianasaif@gmail.com", "test");
                // Smtp Email ID and Password For authentication
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mail);
                return userMessage;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error............" + ex;
            }

        }
```

**1. This is my code to send email

2. Problem is I cannot open Reset Page when clicked on URL
3. I have created the virtual directory as well**

Comment: It should be  "http://localhost/LoginWithSession/ResetPassword//" + userID. I think you have missed / after url

Comment: Wouldn't you need an <a> tag around the link to make sure that it's handled as a link?

Comment: There's no link in that email, so there's nothing to click

Comment: First things first - don't write you own password reset code. Don't write your own authentication code. ASP.NET MVC already contains a *secure* authentication mechanism that includes password resets

Comment: Second, an HTML email is still an HTML document, and email clients are far less forgiving than browsers. If you want a link in that document, you need to add an `<a>` tag, just like any other page. Email clients won't auto-convert plain text to links for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Three, SmtpClient is deprecated. There's a very big yellow warning [at the top of the class's doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netcore-3.1) that says it's obsolete. The [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) section suggests using MailKit instead

Comment: Finally, this code is insecure and would allow someone to reset all passwords by simply trying that URL with consecutive User IDs. This can be used to retrieve user names too, just by trying all IDs and screen scraping the responses that probably include the username. ASP.NET MVC's reset feature sends a unique token instead, to prevent just that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this 
Here you need to add `<a>` tag for called the URL.

```
//Create one function for getting URL run time like localhost or any domain name 
public string GetUrl()
{
   var request = Request;
   return string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority, (new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(request.RequestContext)).Content("~"));
}

private string sendEmail(string emailId,string userID)
{
    try
    {               
        userID = Encrypt(userID);
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(emailId);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("");
        //mail.Subject = "Your password for account " + emailId;
        string userMessage = string.Concat("<a href='",GetUrl(), "LoginWithSession/ResetPassword/", userID,"'>");

        userMessage = userMessage + "<br/><b>User Id:</b> " + emailId+"</a>";
        //userMessage = userMessage + "<br/><b>Passsword: </b>" + password;

        string Body = "<br/><br/>Please  click on link to reset your password:<br/></br> " + userMessage + "<br/><br/>Thanks";
        mail.Body = Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //SMTP Server Address of gmail
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        // Smtp Email ID and Password For authentication
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
        return userMessage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Error............" + ex;
    }

}
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful unless they are obvious. How does that help answer the question? How is this different from the original code? Where's the `<a>` tag? This won't work any better than the original code. Email clients won't treat URL-like text in an HTML body as if it were an `<a>`

Comment: It is not working as the link disappears when email is sent.